# Jlist just show 2 element at last

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to show list player to Jlist, but it doesn't show all of list, just 2 element at last.
This is my code:

```
           //create List player

    listplayersource = new DefaultListModel();
    listplayersource.addElement("VIP player 1");        
    list_player = new JList(listplayersource);
    list_player.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list_player.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list_player.setVisibleRowCount(16);     
    panelmain.add(new JScrollPane(list_player), BorderLayout.WEST);

    listplayersource.addElement("Vip player 2");

    listplayersource.addElement("VIP player 2");
    listplayersource.addElement("VIP player 3");
    listplayersource.addElement("VIP player 4");
    listplayersource.addElement("VIP player 5");
```

Result:

```
      VIP player 4

      VIp player 5
```

What is wrong at it?
[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to the screenshot ?

Comment: i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You can post a link, I believe, in the comments

Comment: here, help me .link result: http://i.upanh.com/rclozx

Comment: Mozilla says there was an error opening the page. Try uploading to imgur

Comment: try it: http://upanh.com/view/?s=null&id=5rc9dlfo5zx

Comment: I still cannot see it. Plus, it is in Vietnamese so I have difficulty understanding what it says. http://imgur.com/

Comment: i will upload to facebook

Comment: hope you can see it: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=318153791657817&set=a.318153828324480.1073741826.100003895959434&type=1&theater

Comment: imgur: http://imgur.com/9vtCIyV

Comment: Ok I have edited your question to display the image

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok, i found what i'm wrong.It just i have panel over panel and i can't see it. Thank you.